Installing Ubuntu 24.04 in VirtualBox 7.1.4 on macOS 15.x with M1 Apple Silicon
I have the following configuration.
   MacBook Pro M1 MAX
   32 GB RAM
   2 TB
   VirtualBox 7.1.4 r165100 (Qt6.5.3)
I want to install Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 in a VM.
   8 virtual CPUs
   8GB RAM
   30GB VDI storage
Unfortunately the system is not booting from the iso although all settings are correct. The below screenshots show the settings and the results.
General setting of my VM:

Detailed virtualized SCSI for HDD and CD:

This is the output I get when I run the VM:

